# Spring GCP cloud run spring boot 3 Micromter customized context propagation to look primarily for x-cloud-trace-context

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, spring-cloud-gcp, spring-gcp

Spring boot 3 with GCP

https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/spring-cloud-gcp/reference/html/index.html#tracing

Here it says

In the case of StackdriverTracePropagation, first it looks for trace context in the X-B3 headers (X-B3-TraceId, X-B3-SpanId). If those are not found, StackdriverTracePropagation will fall back on x-cloud-trace-context key (e.g., an HTTP request header).

Wanted to customize this behavious to use x-cloud-trace-context, any samples would be of great help